# BroadcastReceiver works on earlier android versions, but on newer not

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I've got a following problem:
Why does my CallReceiver works on older android version, while on the newer one nothing happens? Is it any change of permission rules, or what?
There is my code:

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    static boolean isRinging=false;
    static boolean isReceived=false;
    static String callerPhoneNumber;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context mContext, Intent intent){

        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);


        if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
            isRinging =true;
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            callerPhoneNumber= bundle.getString("incoming_number");
        }

        if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
            isReceived=true;
        }

        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
            // detect missed call
            if(isRinging==true && isReceived==false){
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Missed call from : "+callerPhoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver
        android:name=".CallReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: PhoneState is now a dangerous permission-  you need to do a runtime permission check.  I'm not sure how that works with a receiver registered in the manifest

Comment: Did you verified runtime permissions on newer versions?

Comment: I didn't, it is probably a solution, thanks a lot. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your question, it seems you didn't asked for Run time permissions on higher versions(>=API level 23), so enable them by requesting permissions.

For more check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).